# Analyse the performance of an rsync command from FreeNAS to a USB drive

Tags: freebsd, rsync, performance, usb-drive, freenas

I infrequently run a task where I `rsync` my photos (~30 directories with 10-100 files in each) from my FreeNAS machine to an external USB hard drive (500GB WD) as a redundant backup.

I execute the following commands:

```
mount_msdosfs -o large /dev/da1s1 /mnt/usbbak/
rsync -rtvu /mnt/volume1/home/demo/Photos/camera /mnt/usbbak/
```

After the above `rsync` command has made it through half of all the files it begins to slow down. To the point where the machine/FreeNAS becomes unresponsive for several seconds/minutes. At this point I skip the current directory and `rsync` the rest of the files fine. However when I go back to `rsync` the directory I skipped the slow down reappears.

I am not sure where to begin or how to debug/determine what could be happening? Is this an `rsync` issue? Maybe an issue with the USB hard drive?

Comment: Does the `mount` option for mdsosfs include `flush`? it might help...

Answer (score 2):

I always add `-v` switches to `rsync` when attempting to debug what's going on.

```
$ rsync -v ....
```

If you need more verbosity add more `-v` switches:

```
$ rsync -vv
```

Since you've already added `-v` and it's not giving you any additional insights it's unlikely that more `-v`'s will do much else.

#### Debugging further

*Idea #1*

Since you're issue seems to be specific to this directory I'd continue to break it down, there is something obviously unique about this directory that's the culprit for your issue.

I'd continue running `rsync` on portions of this directory until you localize the issue to a directory or perhaps a single file. I'd be suspicious of directories with links or device files perhaps, or FIFOs.

*Idea #2*

I would also omit the `-t` switch on this directory as a test to see if it's an issue with the modification times.

*Idea #3*

Also I usually opt for the switches `-avz`, if you don't have a particular reason for your switches you might want to go with these grouping instead, at least on this directory as you debug the issue further.

*Idea #4*

I'm not sure how much of the filesystem "features" carry over from MSDOS styles of filesystems vs. EXT3/4. What is the target filesystem on the USB drive? Is it also a MS based one? I did find this bug filed that was regarding `msdosfs` and poor performance, titled: [extremely bad USB/msdos performance](http://bugs.dragonflybsd.org/issues/1527).

**NOTE:** Remember that FreeNAS is making use of FreeBSD under the hood, so you're looking for issues that would involve, `msdosfs`, `rsync`, and FreeBSD for starters.

*Idea #5*

My experience with USB based transfers is that they generally queue up and then can level off. Are you hitting against poor performance because of the external HDD? I'd try a test of `rsync`'ing the data to another location on the NAS if possible, to at the very least eliminate the USB external drive as a source of the issue.

Comment: `Idea 1`: This directory has 248 files in it and this method has shown an issue after files 78 ~ 100 and after files 219 ~ 248. Using -vv showed some `.hidden` file errors (e.g. 'rsync: chown ".DSC_0190.NEF.77drq5" failed: Invalid argument (22)'). I am assuming this is a temp `rsync` file as `ls -al` shows no `.hidden` files. `Idea 2 & 3`: No Change. `Idea 4`: The target filesystem is msdosfs. `Idea 5': On deck, I'll try soon.